# DllImport C Sharp const char*

Tags: c#

Hy all,

I want to make from a unmanaged dll to a managed dll in C#.

in the documentation it is:

```
typedef void*    AP_HANDLE
typedef uint32_t ap_u32

AP_HANDLE ap_CreateVirtual(const char *szFilename)

void ap_SetState(AP_HANDLE apbase, const char *szState, int nValue)

unsigned char *ap_ColorPipe(AP_HANDLE      apbase, 
                            unsigned char *pInBuffer,
                            ap_u32         nInBufferSize, 
                            ap_u32        *rgbWidth, 
                            ap_u32        *rgbHeight, 
                            ap_u32        *rgbBitDepth)
```

In C++ works fine, but in C# the syntax is the problem
It seems I can't make not evan the first function work

```
public unsafe class appbase
{
    [DllImport("D:\\apbase.dll", EntryPoint = "ap_CreateVirtual")]
    //, CharSet = UnicodeEncoding
    //, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall

    public static extern void* ap_CreateVirtual(char* szFilename);
}
```

and

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        unsafe
        {
            void* ap_handle = null;

            appbase APPbase = new appbase();

            string s = "D:\\ASX.xsdat";

            fixed (char* p = s)
            {
                ap_handle = APPbase.ap_CreateVirtual(p);
            }

            return;
        }
    }
```

tried with argument for ap_CreateVirtual string, String*, char*, char[] and put a break point on return; the ap_handle was always with value 0x0000

what is the proper way to import these functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char*` is the default marshaling for a .NET string.

```
[DllImport("D:\\apbase.dll", EntryPoint = "ap_CreateVirtual", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
//, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall
public static extern System.IntPtr ap_CreateVirtual(string szFilename);
```

Your original attempt was wrong because `char` in C# is C++'s `wchar_t`, not C++ `char`.

If you need a C++ `char` in C#, it's either `byte` or `sbyte`.  But p/invoke will simply do the right thing with `System.String`.

Comment: with CharSet = CharSet.Ansi it breaks down and with CharSet = CharSet.Unicode it passes but the pointer is still 0 after ... so it dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Just copying over the C++ headers isn't enough. You need to understand what the arguments actually mean and how they are represented. The first function is simple enough:

```
[DllImport("...", EntryPoint="ap_CreateVirtual")]
public static extern IntPtr ap_CreateVirtual(
  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szFilename);
```

I assume that in the second, `szState` is again a simple LPStr, while the `pInBuffer` is most likely a fixed-length `byte[]` with size determined by `nInBufferSize`. `rgbXXX` seem to be `ref` arguments. The return type may again be a LPStr.

Comment: it's seems it still breaks down after the call of s = "D:\\ASX.xsdat"; ap_CreateVirtual(s);

Comment: @dorin.petre That most likely means you need to change the calling convention as well, probably to `CallingConvention.Cdecl` (the proper calling convention should be part of the documentation, but if it isn't, Cdecl is probably the one you want for C-style functions). Also, make sure the native DLL and your app have the same bitness - .NET applications are AnyCPU by default, so on a 64-bit system they wouldn't be able to call a 32-bit native DLL. And what exactly "breaks down"?